# No se ven mis bases de datos en instancia de google-cloud-platform

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-platform

He creado una instancia en GCP en la sección de Bases de Datos muestra las bases de datos del sistema y las que se han creado no se muestran.

Si es cuestion de permisos, como se cambian los permisos del usuario o como se cambian los permisos de la base de datos?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Si creaste la Base de Datos y no se ve en la lista de bases de datos te recomiendo que intentes refrescar la ventana o abrirlo desde el modo de Incognito para verificar que no sea un problema de tu caché local no actualizando la ventana.

Si aún así no ves las bases de datos creadas entonces te recomiendo que crees un Bug en [Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187202&template=0) (la página para reportar bugs de Google Cloud Platform)

Answer (score 0):

No es una solución, es una sugerencia. Trata de utilizar el SDK.

Por ejemplo, para listar las instancias, puedes utilizar:

```
$ gcloud sql instances list
```

Una vez que veas una instancia, puedes hacer:

```
$ gcloud sql database list --instance=<instancia>
```